# JodaTime daylight saving bug

Tags: java, jodatime, dst

I want to create a DateTime object from ISO8601 String (e.g., `2012-11-05T07:00:00+0000`). Here is the code:

```
...
DateTime day = new DateTime(dateStr);
System.out.println(dateStr + "=>" + day);
```

I got these results:

```
...
2012-11-04T07:00:00+0000=>2012-11-04T00:00:00.000-07:00
2012-11-05T07:00:00+0000=>2012-11-04T23:00:00.000-08:00
2012-11-06T08:00:00+0000=>2012-11-06T00:00:00.000-08:00
...
```

`11-04` and `11-06` are correct, but `11-05` are wrong. How to fix it? I am on the west coast of North America.

Comment: What makes you think it is wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't be `2012-11-05T00:00:00.000-07:00`?

Comment: @xuc: Why would you expect it to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In what way is 11-05 wrong? On November 4th at 2am local time (i.e. 9am UTC), [west coast time](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=137) went from UTC-7 to UTC-8.

Now November 5th at 7am UTC, which is your second line, is *after* that point in time, therefore it's correct for it to be UTC-8... and therefore the local time is 11pm on November 4th, exactly as shown.

Joda Time is right here (unsurprisingly).

Comment: You are right. Seems the wrong one is the source (`dateStr`) not JodaTime.